# hello.js library for Twitter, Google+ produces logout error

Tags: oauth-2.0, hello.js

I have problem with logout with twitter and Google+ with hello.js library with auth authentication. I have written logout code it is not working for twitter and Google+ but working with Facebook perfectly.

Code here:

```
hello("google").logout({force:true},function(){
    alert("Signed out");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Logout from the thirdparty is only available with Facebook and Windows http://adodson.com/hello.js/#hellologout